# undefined method `async' (suckerpunch gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, sucker-punch

I am using sucker_punch gem to send the email in my rails app in the background.It used to work fine, but then I suddenly got this error:

```
undefined method `async' for #<ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SuckerPunchAdapter::JobWrapper:0x007f892c6c31a0>
```

Below is the screenshot of the full error:

[image]

I am using sucker_punch version 2.0.1 right now. I have tried to downgrade it and using sucker_punch version 1.6.0 instead, but the error persist.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay I have finally figured it out. In my `sucker_punch.rb` file, I need to include this:

```
# config/initializers/sucker_punch.rb

require 'sucker_punch/async_syntax'
```

This is required for those who are using Sucker Punch version 2.0.0+ with Rails < 5.0.0 as explained [here](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch)

Answer (score 1):

They've actually changed async syntax.

With newer versions of sucker_punch, you should call async like so:
`Model.perform_async`

It's mentioned under the *Backwards Compatibility* heading here
https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch